# Constant warning when running tomcat from intellij

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, intellij-idea

All of a sudden, when i run tomcat from within intellij, the output console is constantly bombarded with messages.

(very) short video showing this:
http://screencast.com/t/ddBhIh3UZiA

The messages constantly output is:

```
16:05:31,157  WARN http-nio-8222-exec-1 servlet.PageNotFound:198 - Request method 'HEAD' not supported
16:05:31,158  WARN http-nio-8222-exec-2 servlet.PageNotFound:1120 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

I am using Spring 4.1 and tomcat 8.
Java 8 and Windows 8.1

This phenomenon didnt use to happen before and it suddently started occuring. What is going on?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'm having the exact same problem.  If you have your Tomcat run configuration set to open a browser on launch, IntelliJ will try to ping the website to ensure it's up prior to opening the browser.  I believe it's doing HEAD requests and since your site isn't set to answer / HEAD requests, you get the error.
Unchecking the "After launch" checkbox under "Open browser" in the server tab of the run configuration fixed it for me.
As for getting JetBrains to fix this, I'm not sure what to do about it.  I did just upgrade to 14.0.3 so that might be the cause...

Comment: you are right this is a problem with intellij 14.0.3. i only noticed this right after upgrade

Comment: it's definitely an issue with 14.0.3. Your solution works, thank you so much.

Answer (score 6):

Solved by JetBrains in this ticket, and if you want you can change a Jar to avoid the regression.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-135196

Answer (score 1):

It seems your client is using HEAD has the request method. It is similar to GET but it says to the server that it must not return message-body in the response.

Either check your pages or client for HEAD requests or accept HEAD as RequestMethod like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.HEAD})
```